# webrtc voice packetization size

Tags: webrtc

I was wondering how can I change voice packets size in webrtc application? I am using opus and I am trying to change packet size from 20 ms to 40 ms. I thought I can achieve it through changing ptime in sdp. However when I captured packets with wireshark there is not difference between packets with ptime=20 and ptime=40 and the difference between consecutive time stamps is always 960. I would expect the difference to be  1920 for 40ms ptime. I imagine I am completely wrong in my assumptions, is there any way to actually change packet sizes?